# How to use the primitive "patch-right-and-ahead" when the world wrapping is disabled in the model settings?

Tags: netlogo

I have a problem with the primitive "patch-right-and-ahead". When the world wrapping is disabled in the model settings, I obtain the following error message:

```
OF expected input to be a turtle agentset or patch agentset or turtle or patch but got NOBODY instead.
```

when I do :

```
if [pcolor] of patch-here = brown [
 if [pcolor] of (patch-right-and-ahead 90 1) = brown [
  move-to patch-right-and-ahead 90 1 ] ]
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a primitive that normally returns an agent can't find an appropriate agent to return, it will return `nobody`. Here, there is no patch that's right and ahead of the current agent (er, since the angle is 90, I guess just right of). Thus, it's returning `nobody`. You need to check to make sure it's not `nobody` before using `of` on it:

```
if [pcolor] of patch-here = brown [
  let target-patch patch-right-and-ahead 90 1
  if target-patch != nobody and [pcolor] of target-patch = brown [
    move-to target-patch
  ]
]
```